# How to analyze a categorical response with 4 levels?

Tags: categorical-data

I'm planning the following experiment: I will put a beetle into a container and record which of four possible options it chooses (replicated across multiple beetles and containers, of course). Normally, this would be a categorical response variable with 4 levels. However, in my experiment these levels are: light and high-quality leaf; light and low-quality leaf; darkness and high-quality leaf; darkness and low-quality leaf. The levels are thus related to each other. I'm interested in the effects of light, leaf quality, any possible interaction between the two, and also beetle sex (which might affect how the beetle responds to light and leaf quality).

An example of what the data might look like (L=light, D=darkness, 1=low quality, 2=high quality):

```
Beetle Sex  Choice
1      M    L1
2      M    L2
3      F    D2
4      F    D1
```

How could I analyze this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would not consider them four options but rather two options on two different (probably connected) decisions. So, best store the data in a format that reflects the choices independently. They may still be combined for some analyses by just concatenating these two columns.

```
  sex Quality Light
1   M       1     L
2   F       2     L
3   M       1     D
4   F       2     D
```

In such a dataset you can do different analyses that are suitable for dichotomous choices:

- Chi-squared tests to determine if there is a connection between Quality and Light.
- Chi-suqared tests to determine if sex has any conneciton to Quality or Light or their combination
- Binomial tests to test whether one option was chosen significantly more often by males or females.

You could also include more variables (experimental treatment etc.) and include them as additional conditions to do a QDA.

Comment: Good suggestion (+1) I would add that once you have split the outcome into 2 binary variables, one additional possibility for adding more predictors is to use a multivariate logit model, e.g. see [this article](https://doi.org/10.1080/07474938.2015.1093780) This would enable also to measure how different predictors influence the correlation between the two binary outcomes..

Comment: If there are some metric predictors and enough data, that would make sense, yes. But given the data in the OP, I would not advise too advanced methods.